# Format exception in retrieving data from data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatexception

I have a data grid view in which i have column of number of citations. i am trying this code to retrieve data from column but its throwing an *format exception* exception,please help here is my code:

```
    int GSCitations = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only mean, that the content of `row.Cells[2]` is not a valid integer and can't be converted to `int`.

Use  [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead

Comment: but row.cells[2] has integers,all of them ,and exception is thrown in first itertion

Comment: @mani1989 : Are you doing this in `rowdatabound`? If so have you check so that it is the `datarow` you are trying to retrieve the value from not the `header` ?

Comment: yes i am doing it in row data bound,when debugging value of gscitation is 441 but exception is thrown

Comment: @mani1989 so if GSCitations is assigned, then the posted line doesn't throw an exception? Are you sure 441 isn't the previously assigned value?